# Why is res.render() not working with req.params.id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I have been trying to make this work on this project about showing dogs for adoption, every other route works perfectly but this one /dog/:id which requires an id from my mongoDB database is not working with res.render().

res.render() is working on other routes without req.params.id

As you can see in the code below the line with this method is commented out and this is the line I want to make work; res.send() works perfectly but I don't know why res.render() does not. Thanks!!!

```
router.route('/dog/:id')
.get(async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    const adoption = await Adoption.findById(id)
        .populate('category');
    const categories = await Category.find();

    /* res.render('default/dog', { adoption: adoption, categories: categories }); */
    res.send(JSON.stringify(adoption));
});
```

By the way, I'm using node.js with express and handlebars for rendering different views for each route.

Comment: What error do you get when using the `res.render`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so after trying to figure out why the hell this was not working I spot the error... and it was not from the backend it was a script tag that was not loading correctly ._. so it was just frontend stuff:

```
<script src="js/revolution.extension.actions.min.js"></script>
```

When not using a route with additional params it works fine but if you want to make it work on every route (I mean, simple ones and the ones with params) you have to include **/** at the very beginning, like this:

```
<script src="/js/revolution.extension.actions.min.js"></script>
```

And it worked!!!

Comment: I just had this problem, doing a college project and I get the backend part, I passed it here and I didn't think that was it, but damn for the guy I copy another guy's front end and it didn't import the correct files. I don't know if it's Express or NodeJS but it ends up fixing this "wrong" import in the html, but when you pass parameters it doesn't do that (or there isn't enough time for the synchronization to do that),

Overall: Double check your imports (js, css, img, html, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a views directory and folder structure something like that:

```
- routes
    | -- index.js
-config
    |-- config.js
- client
    |-- public
    |     | -- js
    |     | -- css
    |     | -- font
- views
    | -- dog.handlebars
    | -- layout
           | -- main.handlebars
- server.js
```

And in server.js you probably initialize handlebars like this:

```
 const hbs = exphbs.create({
        defaultLayout: 'main.handlebars',
        helpers: {....}
        })
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

If this is the case and you do it like that you can simply call res.render with 'dog' like this:

```
res.render('dog', { adoption: adoption, categories: categories });
```

Comment: I did that, it works ok without the param in the route, I mean if I create the route /dog it renders the view normally but when I change it to /dog/:id it doesn't work with res.render (and just to check if everything else was ok I used res.send and it works perfectly but res.render won't render the view)

Comment: try to find the document with a callback or exec not async await it shouldn't be the problem but give it a try
Adoption.findById(id, function(err, adoption){})
Adoption.findById(id).exec(function(err,adoption){})
Accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

res.render doesn't work alone or are you trying to render the template and send the response at the same time? If that is the case than the template will be rendered first but then the json response will be sent so it would look like express is not rendering the template.

If that's not the case and you are only running res.render than check the path default/dog. Is there a directory default inside views inside which you have got the dog handlebars template. Check that also and then tell if it solves your problem

Comment: I have been using res.render on the entire project, it works fine for all views but not for this one which has a req.params.id on the code.